# Passing random seed to numpy random.choice function

Tags: numpy, random-seed

Let's say I have an function that takes a `random_state` argument to ensure replicability

```
def replicable_function(random_seed):
    choice = np.random.choice(X, 10)
    #do more stuff here with choice
    return f(choice)
```

These are my two requirements:

1. Passing the same `random_seed`(could be an integer or a `np.random.RandomState` object) means the `replicable_function` always outputs the same thing
2. I don't change the global numpy random seed state (trying to be nice to the user and not change things she doesn't expect)

Ideally, I'd like to pass this `random_state` to the `np.random.choice` function, but it doesn't seem to take such an argument ([see the source code here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L761)!)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this answer right after asking it here.
I'm not sure it's the best solution though, so I'm happy to receive other suggestions.

I ended up using a utility function from `sklearn` that, if needed, turns an integer input into a `RandomState` instance.

```
def check_random_state(seed):
    """Turn seed into a np.random.RandomState instance

    Parameters
    ----------
    seed : None | int | instance of RandomState
        If seed is None, return the RandomState singleton used by np.random.
        If seed is an int, return a new RandomState instance seeded with seed.
        If seed is already a RandomState instance, return it.
        Otherwise raise ValueError.
    """
    if seed is None or seed is np.random:
        return np.random.mtrand._rand
    if isinstance(seed, (numbers.Integral, np.integer)):
        return np.random.RandomState(seed)
    if isinstance(seed, np.random.RandomState):
        return seed
    raise ValueError('%r cannot be used to seed a numpy.random.RandomState'
                     ' instance' % seed)
```

Thus, I could write:

```
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state

def replicable_function(random_seed):
    random_seed = check_random_state(random_seed)
    choice = random_seed.choice(X, 10) #instead of np.random.choice(X, 10)
    #do more stuff here with choice
    return f(choice)
```